# Quadratic and Logarithmic Inequality

Tags: inequality

> > How can the following be solved algebraically?
> >
> > $$log_{10}(x) > |0.1x^2 - 2x + 3|  $$

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: When would you consider this solved? The solutions can be expressed in terms of the $W_n$-functions, but would you consider that an algebraic solution?

Comment: There are four real solutions, but they do not seem to be algebraic numbers. So I doubt it can be solved algebraically, for any reasonable definition of algebraically.